# Sharing LESS CSS variables with conditional comments

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, less, conditional-comments

I have a LESS stylesheet `styles.less` with some variables that I need to access in my `ie7.css` stylesheet, which is loaded using conditional comments.

Given that these are entirely separate stylesheets, and given that I would have to convert `ie7.css` to `ie7.less`, is it possible for me to make these CSS variables available across the two stylesheets?

i.e. I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
# styles.less, always loaded
@labelwidth: 150px;

# ie7.less, sometimes loaded
label{ margin-left: @labelwidth; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way of doing so is to use only two different stylesheets: one for everyone and one for ie, which includes the everyone's. So, in HTML, using smart Conditional Comments it would look like:

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.less" />
<!--<![endif]--><!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="ie.less">
<![endif]-->
```

And in `ie.less` you can import `styles.less`:

```
@import url(styles.less);

/* Your styles for IE */
```

So, you gain two benefits:

1. You get all the variables from `styles.less` in `ie.less`.
2. You get only one request on IE (it loads only one stylesheet).